# How do I recover from a failure to boot Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrading from 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, 16.04

I recently upgraded my venerable 12.04 Ubuntu Desktop (which was itself upgraded from 8.04 and 10.04) to 14.04, which worked fine (I spent five days checking hundreds of files and settings).  I never used 14.04 because I dislike it so (in fact, the medium-large production organization which I'm on the board of directors for never used 14.04 either, because our customers disliked it... we went straight from 12.04 to 16.04 on our production machines).  But having no other choice if I wanted to retain my settings, I first upgraded to 14.04, then attempted to go to 16.04 five days later... and failed.  The weird thing is the the 4.4.0-20-something kernel for 16.04 is there, but I can only access recovery mode (none of the choices seem to help, from repairing packages to root shell).  A snapshot of the drive can be found at http://paste2.org/phXMyZg6  Any ideas?